# Relativity and volume of black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, density, event-horizon, singularities

Does Einstein's theory of special or general relativity incorporate volume?

In a particle accelerator two particles smash together at relativistic speeds and "create" new particles (quarks etc) due to $E=mc^2$. In our space-time, the volume needed for these new clumps of mass already exists in local space-time.

What happens in the super-dense core of a galaxy where stars and black holes are all sucked together into a super-dense object? Presumably, all the matter has been compressed to its theoretical limit. When another super-dense object (another black hole) strikes it at relativistic speeds, where does the volume come from to accommodate the creation of these new particles? If space-time of a black hole is infinitely curved, how can new volume be created for these particles to occupy?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has attracted the 3 close votes it has. It's a good question that is being actively researched (search ADS for BH-BH mergers, if you don't believe me).

Answer (score 1):

On paper, a black hole already has infinite density.  Two coalescing holes would combine to another object of infinite density.

Realistically, we would need quantum gravity to prevent a true singularity from forming,a nd there, we could address, more concretely, what happens when the "masses" in the center of the black holes merge.  But until we unambiguously have a true theory of quantum gravity, we can't answer this.

And yes, you can compress two stars together enough in a collision that they will collapse to a black hole.

Comment: As an aside, BH-BH mergers are one of the primary suspects for gamma-ray bursts (at least for large redshifts); see [this recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1546).

Comment: @KyleKanos: the link says that NS-NS and NS-BS mergerrs are the suspects, which makes sense, since you need charged matter to generate GRBs.

Comment: Yes, NS-NS & BH-NS mergers are also candidates for GRBs. However, figures 3 & 4 of the link show the merger rate density for BH-BH events as significantly larger than the others (except for the case of High BH kicks, which destroys the binary system so the rate should be lower).

Comment: THe merger rate is higher, but they aren't GRB candidates, because there is no coupling to the EM field.  They are expected to dominate the space of LIGO sources, though.

Comment: Hmm, I could have sworn that BH-BH mergers were expected precursors for long duration GRBs, but the several papers I've pulled up on GRB precursors only involve NS-NS or NS-BH mergers. Thanks for helping me do some investigation!

Answer (score 0):

> If space-time of a black hole is infinitely curved, how can new volume
>   be created for these particles to occupy?

The spacetime of a black hole isn't infinitely curved.  Only at the spacetime singularity *within* a black hole is the curvature infinite.

The spacetime near, at, and within the horizon is highly curved but not infinitely so.

I recommend thinking a little more carefully about this and then reposing your question.

Comment: I think they are specifically asking about the singularity, since this is a question about the mass compression.